# how to align racket GUI text fields and buttons

Tags: user-interface, plugins, scheme, racket

I am creating a GUI for a racket program where a user inputs a title and a blog and then submits it. This is my code for those fields so far:

```
(define blogPost%
  (class horizontal-panel%
    (super-new)
    (define titleoutput (new text-field% (label "    title")
                             (min-height 20)
                             (min-width 200)
                             (vert-margin 20)
                             (horiz-margin 10)
                             (parent this)))
    (define output (new text-field% (label "blog")
                        (style '(multiple))
                        (min-height 20)
                        (vert-margin 20)
                        (min-width 400)
                        (parent this)))
    (define (callback button event)
      (define title-new-value (send titleoutput get-value))
      (define new-value (send output get-value))
      (save title-new-value new-value)
      (send output set-value "")
      (send titleoutput set-value "")
      (send howisit show #t))
    (define button (new button% (label "Submit")
                        (vert-margin 0)
                        (horiz-margin 10)
                        (parent this)
                        (callback callback)))
    ))
```

It is currently aligned like this:

[image]

But I would like the title text box to be above the blog field and the submit button to be centered at the bottom.

Comment: What are `save` and `howisit`? I'm getting unbound identifier errors. It would be helpful to least make dummy implementations like `(define (save title body) (printf "saving ~v as:\n~v\n" title body))` so that it compiles as a complete example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're running this code in the same way as for [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36804247/how-to-wrap-input-text-in-text-field-using-the-racket-gui-plugin). In that, you used your class like this:

```
(define f (new frame% [label "blog post GUI"] [min-width 400] [min-height 500]))

(define tib (new blogPost%
                 [parent f]))

(send f show #t)
```

Now since you defined `blogPost%` as a subclass of [`horizontal-panel%`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/horizontal-panel_.html), it also inherits all of the initialization arguments of [`horizontal-panel%`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/horizontal-panel_.html), including the `alignment` argument. So you can pass the `[alignment '(left top)]` initialization argument to your `blogPost%` class:

```
(define f (new frame% [label "blog post GUI"] [min-width 400] [min-height 500]))

(define tib (new blogPost%
                 [parent f]
                 [alignment '(left top)]))

(send f show #t)
```

If you want to build this default into your `blogPost%` class, you could add it to the `(super-new)` form instead:

```
(define blogPost%
  (class horizontal-panel%
    (super-new [alignment '(left top)])
    ...))
```

However, if you happen to have a `(new blogPost% ... [alignment '(left top)] ...)` around somewhere else, I believe this will break that code.

So to avoid that, it would probably be best to make the `blogPost%` class it's own class, so that instead of *being* a [`horizontal-panel%`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/horizontal-panel_.html), it would *have* a [`horizontal-panel%`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/horizontal-panel_.html), in the same way that it already has two text-fields and a button.

This is better for the long term because after this change, code that uses `blogPost%` won't break if you change which initialization arguments you passed to [`horizontal-panel%`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/horizontal-panel_.html) (which was implicit in the `super-new` previously).

```
(define blogPost%
  (class object% ; object% instead of horizontal-panel%
    ; This argument is explicit now.
    ; If other code relies on other arguments, specify them here.
    (init parent)
    (super-new)
    (define panel
      (new horizontal-panel% ; this new call is explicit now
           [parent parent]   ; you can later add more arguments
           [alignment '(left top)])) ; and it won't break things
    (define titleoutput
      (new text-field%
           [label "    title"]
           [min-height 20]
           [min-width 200]
           [vert-margin 20]
           [horiz-margin 10]
           [parent panel])) ; panel instead of this
    (define output
      (new text-field%
           [label "blog"]
           [style '(multiple)]
           [min-height 20]
           [vert-margin 20]
           [min-width 400]
           [parent panel])) ; panel instead of this
    (define (callback button event)
      (define title-new-value (send titleoutput get-value))
      (define new-value (send output get-value))
      (save title-new-value new-value)
      (send output set-value "")
      (send titleoutput set-value "")
      (send howisit show #t))
    (define button
      (new button%
           [label "Submit"]
           [vert-margin 0]
           [horiz-margin 10]
           [parent panel] ; panel instead of this
           [callback callback]))
    ))

(define f (new frame% [label "blog post GUI"] [min-width 400] [min-height 500]))

(define tib (new blogPost%
                 [parent f]))

(send f show #t)
```

Of course, with this method, you won't be able to use the methods defined for [`horizontal-panel%`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/horizontal-panel_.html) on instances of your `blogPost%` class, but in the long run that's a good thing as well. If you ever, in the future, wanted to change the implementation to use something other than a [`horizontal-panel%`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/horizontal-panel_.html), you could.

Comment: Also my save function saves the variables into a database but it isnt really necessary for the gui. what you did works great!

Comment: I'm just wondering, how much do you understand loose coupling?

Comment: I understand what it is for the most part, how the different sections depend/know about each other and I don't think I necessarily went about this the best way. I just needed a basic clean GUI application and this worked fine.