# TextArea in Racket

Tags: text, textbox, scheme, racket

What is the equivalent of TextArea of Java (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/TextArea.html) in Racket programming? Basically it is an multi-line window where long text can be entered or displayed as a paragraph. I need such area to display many lines of text (user entry is not needed).

I found text-field (https://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/text-field_.html) but not any text-area. There is an area class (https://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/area___.html) but that seems to be more like a panel rather than place for text display. There is a textarea in html context (https://docs.racket-lang.org/html/index.html?q=text-area#%28def._%28%28lib._html%2Fmain..rkt%29._textarea%29%29) but not as an GUI component.

Thanks for your comments/answers.

Comment: I think you’re just looking for [`text%`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/text_.html).

Comment: editor-canvas% with text% works, but I cannot set-text (no such function) into it, only get-text from it.

Comment: You can use a [`text-field%`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/text-field_.html) with the `[style '(multiple)]` option, as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36804247/how-to-wrap-input-text-in-text-field-using-the-racket-gui-plugin/36816989#36816989)

Comment: That also looks to be a very good method.

Comment: Also, if you haven't checked yet, insert method of text% is quite powerful for setting text.

Comment: Yes, I found that. How do I delete all text: (send a-text delete (send a-text get-start-position) (send a-text get-end-position)) ? To set text (using insert), I want to delete all existing text irrespective of if some text is selected.

Comment: To delete all text, try (send a-text erase).